# Merge two sorted singly linked list [Bugged]

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list

Hi can anyone tell me where i went wrong in merging ??
I need just to find bug in my code.
Ther is some Segmentation Fault which only means i may be accessing something not there i guess. As much i see i took care of all the cases.

Please help me with the bug in the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
Node* MergeLists(Node *headA, Node* headB)
{
    if(headA==NULL) return headB;
    if(headB==NULL) return headA;

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    while(headA!=NULL&&headB!=NULL)
    {
        Node *t;
        if(headA->data < headB->data)
        {
            t=headA;
            headA=headA->next;
        }  
        else
        {
            t=headB;
            headB=headB->next;
        }
        if(head==NULL)
        {
            tail=t;
            head=t;
            tail->next=NULL;
        }            
        else
        {
            tail->next=t;
            tail=tail->next;
            tail->next=NULL;
        } 
        if(headA==NULL)
        { tail->next=headB; return head;}
        if(headB==NULL)
        {   tail->next=headA; return head;}
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Have you run this in a debugger and stepped through your code?

Comment: *where* exactly is your segmentation fault?

Comment: I dont know that. I dont have a debugger i am writing in plain text and also i cant do debugging. can u analyse and tell me anything plz

Comment: You probably forgot to set `tail->next = NULL` in one of both lists. Either provide all source code, or use a debugger to find the line where the segmentation fault happens. The latter is preferred. If you don't know how to use a debugger, that's a good point to learn using one (minimal info: add `-g` as flag, use `gdb ./executable`, `run`).

Comment: This is a significant problem already: `if(head==NULL)` ... and `head` was set to NULL.. where? Nowhere. You're evaluating the address in an indeterminate pointer, and invoking **undefined behavior** as a result.

Comment: @Zeta : if a node is added i made sure to add tail->next=NULL, If iam adding whole list at the end then i no need to add the null as the null will be already be there at the end of the list i am adding

Comment: if(head==NULL) You haven't initialized head to NULL

Comment: @user2590100 that's not the lists Zeta is talking about. He's referring to the two lists you passed *in*.

Comment: @WhozCraig : thanks dude that solved, but i thought if it dont point to anything it will be NULL. Now learned something, THanks again for one and all

Comment: Keep in mind that this will have an effect on the original lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's my solution

```
void  merge(Node* a, Node* b, struct Linkedlist* res)
{
if(a!=NULL&&b!=NULL)
{
    if(a->data == b->data)
    {
        nodePushBack(res, a->data);
        merge(a->next, b->next, res);
    }
    else if(a->data < b->data)
    {
        nodePushBack(res, a->data);
        merge(a->next, b, res);
    }
    else{
        nodePushBack(res, b->data);
        merge(a, b->next,res);
    }
}
while(a!=NULL&&b == NULL)
{
    nodePushBack(res, a->data);
    a = a->next;
}
while(a==NULL&&b!=NULL)
{
    nodePushBack(res, b->data);
    b = b->next;
}
}
```